# Kafka Streams: Kerberos ticket renewal

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, apache-kafka-streams, jaas

When the Kafka stream app is started, the following jaas file is being used.  However, the tickets are not being renewed automatically by the stream application.  It fails with the exception below after the ticket expires.  What should we do to keep the Kerberos ticket automatically renewed?

```
KafkaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
doNotPrompt=true
useTicketCache=true
principal="astvy@DEV.ACM.COM"
useKeyTab=true
serviceName="kafka"
keyTab="/home/astvy/astvy.headless.keytab"
renewTGT=true
client=true;
};
```

Error

```
Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record (key ED1812 value org.cox.model.HourlyUnit@83e6c99 timestamp 1536165112061) to topic dub_hourlyunit_source1 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: 
An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: 
GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]) occurred when evaluating SASL token received from the Kafka Broker. 
Kafka Client will go to AUTHENTICATION_FAILED state.
```

> After making few corrections as below (key change is to set the useTicketCache to false), we have not seen the above issue reoccurring, but as the renewal TGT is set for 7 days, we are continuing to monitor if the issue has been resolved.  Will check for few more days and confirm on this, if the following changes addresses the issue permanently.

```
KafkaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
doNotPrompt=true
useTicketCache=false
principal="astvy@DEV.ACM.COM"
useKeyTab=true
serviceName="kafka"
keyTab="/home/astvy/astvy.headless.keytab"
storeKey=true;
};
```

Comment: I would recommend to follow up on the Kafka mailing list. This might be a bug in the clients.

Comment: If you are able to recreate this issue, could you run with debug logging enabled (at least for KerberosLogin)? It will be good if you can create a JIRA for Apache Kafka with the logs attached. We don't have sufficient testing around ticket refresh, so if there are configs we dont handle correctly, we can try and fix for the next release. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Matthias, Rajini, please see above.  We are still monitoring the behavior and will let you know if we continue to observe the same issue. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 3):

Kafka Streams use Kerberos and SSL just like any other Kafka clients like producer and consumer in the configs, so I cannot really think of any issues inside Streams itself that may cause to not renew ticket.

I did some quick search on Google and one that may be related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10786, if you are using J8.

Comment: Hi Guozhang, please see above.  We are still monitoring the behavior and will let you know if we continue to observe the same issue. Thanks for looking into this.